# Building Chromium with GCC 5.2.0: -Wstrict-overflow=1 warning

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, chromium

I'm attempting to build Chromium 45.0.2454.85 with GCC 5.2.0. It's setup to build with -Wall and -Werror and I'd like to keep it that way (though GCC seems to be making that progressively more difficult in each new version). I've already fixed several warnings (errors) but getting to the bottom of this one is proving pretty tricky:

```
ui/gfx/image/image_util.cc:50:6: error: assuming signed overflow does not occur when assuming that (X - c) <= X is always true [-Werror=strict-overflow]
```

Here is the line it is referring to:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/45.0.2454.85/ui/gfx/image/image_util.cc#50

My first issue with this warning is that it points you to the function that the problem is in and makes you go hunt for the problem. I understand this warning is probably generated somewhere in the guts of the optimizer long after it's lost track of which machine code corresponds to which exact line but that's no solace when faced with tracking down the problem. With a little experimentation (removing the -1 for instance) I was able to verify my suspicion that line 81 is causing the problem (unless I'm totally off track):

```
for (int x = bitmap.width() - 1; x > inner_min; --x) {
```

My second issue is that it's saying that `(X - c) <= X` is always true. Based on my experimentation it seems to be talking about the comparison on line 81 but I don't see how it could be coming to this conclusion.

What is GCC doing here and what is the proper way to fix it? I don't want to go changing int's to unsigned int's to avoid the undefined signed overflow behavior in order to side step the problem.

From GCC Manual -Wstrict-overflow=1:

> Warn about cases that are both questionable and easy to avoid. For
>   example: x + 1 > x; with -fstrict-overflow, the compiler will simplify
>   this to 1. This level of -Wstrict-overflow is enabled by -Wall; higher
>   levels are not, and must be explicitly requested.

I'd also argue that this situation doesn't meet the criteria of "easy to avoid"; please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is that the entire output from GCC? Doesn't it show a more precise location with a caret? It shouldn't just point you to the function.

Comment: Secondly, `(X - c) <= X` _is_ always true for any non-negative `c`, because the only way it could be false is if `X` underflows and wraps around, which would be undefined behaviour. If you're right about the line that causes the warning it implies the compiler thinks `x > inner_min` is always false and so the loop won't ever be entered. If so, that looks like a bug in GCC.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it points to the first character in the function name which is basically no help at all so I omitted it.

Comment: Agreed, that's no help at all.

Comment: the referenced code is C++, please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: this is C++ code, so 'gcc' will not properly compile it.  suggest using 'g++'

Comment: If you ignore the previous loop and propagate the initial value of `inner_min`, which is `bitmap.width()`, then the warning looks reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

this line from gcc:

```
ui/gfx/image/image_util.cc:50:6: error: ...
```

is saying the problem is in file image_util.cc, line 50, column 6

If '50:6' is the first char of the function name,  there are only a couple of possibilites.

```
1) the function declaration (not something deep in the body) has a problem 
(suggest checking the parameters and comparing to the function prototype)

2) the prior line of the source code contains the problem.
```

If this is just one of a series of problems listed, then

fix the first problem listed, re-compile, repeat until no problems listed

because C compilers tend to spew lots of warnings/errors when the actual root of the problem is at or just before the line indicated

Comment: Without trying to sound disrespectful, you're totally off base with this answer. Try reading the question again more carefully.